# Extracting array values based on values in different dimension

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, indexing

I've got a problem with subsetting values of an array.

```
raw.table <- array(data = c(1:12,13:24,rep(1:6, each=2)), 
                   dim=c(3,4,3),
                   dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3],1:4,c("target","ctrl","samples")))
```

The first two dimensions of my array represent some values that I want to do statistics on and the higher dimensions contain different attributes I want to use to access specific subsets. In this case I have only sample numbers, whereas there are always two values assigned to the same sample number (measurement replicates).

```
, , target

  1 2 3  4
A 1 4 7 10
B 2 5 8 11
C 3 6 9 12

, , ctrl

   1  2  3  4
A 13 16 19 22
B 14 17 20 23
C 15 18 21 24

, , samples

  1 2 3 4
A 1 2 4 5
B 1 3 4 6
C 2 3 5 6
```

How do I access the values in dimension 1 (= target) that have the same sample number denoted in dimension 3 (= samples)? I tried out different approaches using unique(), duplicated() and match() but without coming to a result. I just cannot wrap my head about the indexing of arrays -.-

Cheers,
zuup

Comment: What is your expected output?  Perhaps `which(raw.table[,,1]==raw.table[,,3])`

Comment: My desired output would be a vector of the two values in `raw.table[,,1]` that correspond to the same sample number in `raw.table[,,3]`. So I don't want to compare values of different dimensions (see your answer), but rather compare internally in one dimension and use the result to index values in a different dimension.

Comment: I understand that, but I guess you have only two elements to compare i.e. `target` and `samples` or is there something that we don't know.

Comment: `raw.table[,,1][raw.table[,,3]==x]` returns two values of sample number x. If upper value of sample number is not large (< ten thousand),  `d <- sapply( sort(unique(c(raw.table[,,3]))), function(x) raw.table[,,1][raw.table[,,3]==x])'`returns what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Form a logical index with a logical test (across dimensions):

```
> raw.table[,,1] == raw.table[,,3]
      1     2     3     4
A  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
B FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
C FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And use it to select items from the first dimension (and since they will be equal length there is no recycling):

```
> raw.table[, , 1 ][ raw.table[,,1] == raw.table[,,3] ]
[1] 1
```

Chaining calls to the Extract-operator is perfectly acceptable in R